# Флэш и debian live

Tags: debian, live-usb

Подскажите пожалуйста как создать загрузочную флэшку с двумя разделами на 1-ом разделе которой будет находиться debian livecd, а на втором можно будет хранить данные. 
Я пробовал несколько вариантов:
Разделы на флэшке создавал через fdisk; далее mkfs.ext4
1) образ .ISO копировал через dd
2) образ .ISO конвертировал в гибридный через isohybrid
и записывал через dd на флэш
3) unetbootin
все три варианта не помогли. При загрузке из биос livecd не загружается

Comment: Во-первых, ``unetbootin`` - шлак, и использовать его не надо. Во-вторых, по сабжу, ответ дам чуть позже.

Comment: по сабжу: http://linuxgeeks.ru/live-usb.htm

Comment: Спасибо за отклик. Следовал по инструкции, но пришлось отклониться от указанных путей syslinux _( dd if=/usr/share/syslinux/mbr.bin ... )_ в packages.debian.org выяснил _/usr/lib/SYSLINUX/mbr.bin_ далее недочётов не было. При загрузке из биос пишет "missing operation system". Я сохранил содержимое окна командной строки: http://rgho.st/7hhFKbHcb

Comment: вообще-то debian-installer именно и предназначен для установки. загружаете компьютер (или виртуальную машину) с любого установочного носителя, подкючаете блочное устройство на usb, и производите на него установку (попутно размечая б.у. так, как требуется).

Comment: Разобрался. Забыл сделать загрузочным первый раздел через fdisk a. misdeed спасибо за помощь, а также alexander barakin за отклик. Вопрос закрыт